# How to Assign a PNG image from TPngImageList to TuniImage?

Tags: delphi, png, delphi-xe2

Delphi XE2 Update 4

I have loaded several PNG files 128x128 on TPngImageList and I was to pick one, or either by index number or name, and assign to the TuniImage.Picture

TUniImage is from UniGUi framework. However it is a TPicture class. I guess should be the same of other TPictures that use it.

Comment: Can you let us know exactly what `TPngImageList` is?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I got it from CodeCentral, it was posted by Uwe Raabe http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/26127

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a `TPicture`, as you say, then you assign its `Graphic` property like this:

```
Picture.Graphic := SomeGraphic;
```

So, where does `SomeGraphic` come from. I'm not clear which `TPngImageList` you are using. So, the code to extract a `TGraphic` from the `TPngImageList` might look like this:

```
SomeGraphic := PngImageList.PngImages[0].PngImage;
```